# Spring MVC limit bandwidth of stream transmission

Tags: spring, rest

I need to convert **REST** service written using **JAX-RS** to **Spring MVC**. Case is that this service needs to limit bandwidth while transferring stream of bytes. Currently it's achieved by `javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput`, I'm not able to find any equivalent in Spring.

Any tips appreciated

Regards

Comment: You can get OutputStream or even HttpServletResponse to your Spring Controller method so you can write entire response by yourself at the pace you want.